# C++ override virtual method with abstract class as a parameter

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract-methods

I have a following abstract class

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo(A* a) = 0;
}
```

and several classes inheriting from this class. e.g

```
class B : public A {
public:
    void foo(A* a); // implementation in a separete file
}
```

However, I only want class `B` to accept itself as an argument in `foo`

```
void foo(B* b);
```

Is it possible to do this in C++?
I've considered a template but the syntax allows too much flexibility. It is possible to write `class B: public A<B>`, but I want a compiler error with `class B: public A<C>`.

**-- Edit --**

It seems like my use of abstract class is not justified. Let me clarify my situation.

I am utilizing a polymorphic behavior of `A` in a separate function. In addition to that, I want to define a function that takes in an argument of the same type such as the one above. I am trying to write a function that defines the distance between two objects of a derived class. Distance is only defined between objects from the same class (`b1` and `b2`, or `c1` and `c2`, but not `b1` and `c2`). I also would like to access this distance function in a general way as possible.

**-- Edit 2--**

Cássio showed why it is not possible to perform compiler based checking. zar's solution adds slightly more structure to the code with runtime error checking.

Comment: Why do you want to make things polymorphic and non-polymorphic at the same time?

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way. It is not known until runtime what is 1) the actual derived class that gets passed to `foo()`, for a given call to this virtual function, or 2) whether the instance being called is `A` or `B`. So, nothing can be checked at compile-time.

Comment: @NickyC I am utilizing a polymorphic behavior of A, but also need to have a notion of distance between classes derived from A (e.g. B). Since distance is defined only between derived classes (B and B, or C and C). I also would like to access this distance measure in a general way as possible. (Hence, I thought an abstract class would be a reasonable solution, but it does not seem to the case according to the responses.)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your input. Is there a way around? What do you usually do if you are faced in a similar scenario?

Comment: I redesign my class hierarchy, and how my classes work, so that I can use the type safety features of the C++ language correctly. Virtual functions are dynamic, runtime binding. If I need compile time type checking, I will use something else.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. I would like to know more about your "something else."

Comment: Well, if I need a function that can only take a pointer to `B` as a parameter, then that's what I will use, instead of using a function that takes a pointer to `A`, its superclass, as a parameter, and just hope against hope that it will always be `B`. It is the only way to guarantee it. The only way, in C++, to guarantee that a compiler will verify that your function gets a `B *` parameter is to declare it as such. That's it. It's not complicated. The End.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question is more about the syntax. What you have is right, just pass an  object of type B. The definition will still say A but it will be happy to take the derived class. You don't need any special definition for this.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo(A* a) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo(A* a)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<B*> (a) == NULL)
            std::cout << "wrong type, expecting type B\r\n";
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void foo(A* a)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<C*> (a) == NULL)
            std::cout << "wrong type, expecting type C\r\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    B * b1 = new B;
    B * b2 = new B;

    C * c1 = new C;
    C * c2 = new C;

    b2->foo(c1); // bad

    c1->foo(b1); // bad

    b2->foo(b1); // good

    delete b1;
    delete b2;
    delete c1;
    delete c2;
}
```

see also [dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246293/841330).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to have some type safety when foo is called with other inherited class of A. e.g. say C inherits A, then I don't want people calling b->foo(c). Is there a neat way of doing this in C++?

Comment: I have updated the code. You could check for the type in the function and act accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer. I think you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` for the comparison, though.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `virtual` is for.

`virtual` is there to enable polymorphic behavior. Basically, to enable this:

```
struct A {virtual void foo()=0;};

// Two different "behaviors" for the same "A"
struct B {void foo() override{}};
struct C {void foo() override{}};

// forgive the leak, this is just to prove a point.
A* b = new B();
A* c = new C();
b->foo(); // Will call B::foo, even though this is a pointer to "A"
c->foo(); // Will call C::foo, even though this is a pointer to "A"
```

The way you're trying to use it, you lose this benefit, and you just get the performance hit of virtual functions for nothing. The fact that instantiating a class that doesn't implement some pure virtual function is an error is merely to prevent ill-formed programs.

If you want to make sure `B` implements some interface, simply use that interface somewhere. If `B` does not implement it, you will get the compiler error you're looking for:

```
class B {};

template<typename T> void call_foo(T* v1, T* v2) {
    v1->foo(&v2);
}

B b1;
B b2;
b1.foo(&b2); // error
call_foo(&b1, &b2); // error
```

Then, to get rid of the error, you can just implement the function. No `virtual` needed:

```
class B {
    void foo(B*) {/*do something*/}
};

B b1;
B b2;
b1.foo(&b2); // ok
call_foo(&b1, &b2); // ok
```

---

### But, why can't I use a virtual function for this?

Imagine the following scenario:

```
struct A {virtual void foo(A*)=0;};

// Imagine if the language allowed this:
struct B {void foo(B*) override{}};
struct C {void foo(C*) override{}};

// (...)

// I create a vector of objects, and insert three of them in this vector.
std::vector<A*> objects;

// Note that foo is well-defined only for the first two.
objects.push_back(new B();)
objects.push_back(new B();)
objects.push_back(new C();)

// Then I shuffle the vector
std::shuffle(objects.begin(), objects.end());

// At least one of these three lines should give a compiler error.
// Which one(s)?
objects[0]->foo(objects[1]);
objects[0]->foo(objects[2]);
objects[1]->foo(objects[2]);
```

---

### But I need the function to be virtual, and I need type safety!

Virtual functions are a runtime mechanism. You will have to check the type at runtime. [zar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397424/3854787) already covers this up nicely, so I won't get into the details. To sum it up: simply `dynamic_cast` into the type you want, and if the cast returns `nullptr`, you have the wrong type. You can then throw an exception or print some diagnostic message.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Is it possible to do something like 
A* b1 = new B(); A* b2 = new B(); call_foo<B>(b1, b2). where
void call_foo(T* v1, T* v2) {
    v1->(v2);
}
?

Comment: I meant v1->foo(v2) above.

Comment: Thanks, @Cássio. Your answer is very detailed and super helpful. I, however, decided to take zar's approach this time.